# Read excel file stored in SharePoint Document Library

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I have an excel file stored in SharePoint document library. I need to read this excel file and get the data programmatically from the file path

For Example: 
SharePoint Site: http:// servername :1000

Excel file path :http://servername:1000/ExcelDocs//ExcelFile.xlsx

As we see I have path to excel file stored in SharePoint document library. I need to get data from this file. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I have stored the excel file from the url into a temporary folder inside SharePoint root directory(layouts folder) but for some reasons the temp folder is not create(access denied). I need a method to directly get the data from the file url without having to store in temp location

Answer (score 5):

In fact, you could read Excel file content without any third-party components involved, using SharePoint capabilities only.

The solution demonstrates how to *consume SharePoint REST service to read excel data*. Another point about this approach, since there is **no** any dependencies to SharePoint libraries at all, neither server side nor client side assemblies are referenced.

> Prerequisite: [Excel Services service application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms546696(v=office.14).aspx) has to be configured

### Prepare excel data

Assume the following excel file

[image]

that contains the following items in the workbook:

- table (how to [Create or delete an Excel table in a worksheet](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Create-or-delete-an-Excel-table-in-a-worksheet-867f3add-0522-493c-94ab-b1b9933f46ca))
- chart

Before uploading file into SharePoint library, go to `File -> Browse View Options ->  choose Items in the Workbook` as demonstrated below. Then save file and upload it into SharePoint `Documents` library.

[image]

### How to read excel data via Excel Services 2010 REST API

The following example demonstrates how to read *excel table content* using [Excel Services 2010 REST API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jid1b.png):

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace SharePoint.Client.Office
{
    public class ExcelClient : IDisposable
    {

        public ExcelClient(Uri webUri, ICredentials credentials)
        {
            WebUri = webUri;
            _client = new WebClient {Credentials = credentials};
        }


        public string ReadTable(string libraryName,string fileName, string tableName,string formatType)
        {
            var endpointUrl = string.Format("{0}/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/{1}/{2}/Model/Tables('{3}')?$format={4}", WebUri,libraryName,fileName, tableName, formatType);
            return _client.DownloadString(endpointUrl);
        }


        public void Dispose()
        {
            _client.Dispose();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        public Uri WebUri { get; private set; }

        private readonly WebClient _client;

    }
}
```

**Usage**

The example demonstrates  how to read table content using JSON format:

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName,password,domain);  
var client = new ExcelClient(webUri, credentials);
var tableData = client.ReadTable("Documents","ciscoexpo.xlsx", "CiscoSalesTable","html");
```

### References

- [Using the Excel Services 2010 REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff961897%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
- [Create or delete an Excel table in a worksheet](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Create-or-delete-an-Excel-table-in-a-worksheet-867f3add-0522-493c-94ab-b1b9933f46ca)

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the binary data from SPFile object and then open it in third party library [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

```
SPFile file = web.GetFile("http://servername:1000/ExcelDocs//ExcelFile.xlsx");
Stream dataStream = file.OpenBinaryStream();
XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook(dataStream);
```

or you can use [OpenXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ee358824.aspx), which is Microsoft SDK.

```
SPFile file = web.GetFile("http://servername:1000/ExcelDocs//ExcelFile.xlsx");
Stream dataStream = file.OpenBinaryStream();
SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(dataStream, false);
Workbook workbook = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook;
```

Here is the [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh180830%28v=office.14%29.aspx) of using OpenXML

Comment: Can you please tell me what is XLWorkbook here? does it belong to third party library?

Comment: Yes. It is a part of ClosedXML library. The link is in the begining of my answer

Comment: Any method without third party libraries?

Comment: You can use OpenXML SDK http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ee358824.aspx witch is not a third party library

Comment: @Dmitry Dovgopoly: I knew it a very old post. but i am getting same issue. i am trying your suggestion but it is not resolved my issue. i downloaded and installed openXML SDK then added as reference in my project imported on my page but **SPFile** keyword is not popping up. any suggestion?

Comment: @JasbirBhinder SPFile is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.aspx. You should add `Microsoft.SharePoint` reference to your project.

Comment: @Dmitry hello: could you please tel me how to get Microsoft.SharePoint reference. Right now it is not in my VS2013 express. and i also searched in my full computer for Microsoft.SharePoint.dll file, but noting i found to reference. I downloaded SharepointDesigner from this [link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/9/B/79B9134E-D725-41AC-A04A-053BA7F0D678/SharePointDesigner.exe) but still no reference in my VS2013 express.

Comment: Do you have sharepoint installed? Do you actually need sharepoint or you just want to work with excel file?

Comment: I do not have Sharepoint installed on my pc.I just need to work with Excel file; and that excel file is in our company's sharepoint server.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21786 to use Sharepoint Object Model. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/8d4216c3-2a29-4e92-8229-b7cd2d69e612/client-object-model-download-file-pdfcsvdocimg-from-document-library-using-managed-code?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious to get files from remote sharepoint server and then you can use  OpenXML/ClosedXML to work with excel file

Comment: I installed SharePoint Foundation 2010 Client Object Model Redistributable, and in references manager it is visible in COM> type libraries its not in Assemblies section. I added it and it is visible as OWSSUPP in references. but when i type import microsoft. then noting related to sharepoint come up!!!
SPSite keyword is still an issue

Comment: I found Microsoft.sharepoint.dll from this [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint.Client) but still **SPFile** not available in my windows form.