# Read Write Sharepoint Excel xlsx file from client computer

Tags: vb.net, excel, sharepoint

I am trying to read/write data from excel xlsx file, stored on **Sharepoint** server, using visual basic

I googled a lot but not found any solution related to  connect **remote** location xlsx file

this is my simple code

```
Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim cn As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim DataSet1 As New DataSet
    Dim filePath As String = "http://bhinderblink.com/Test.xlsx"
    cn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & filePath & "'; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";")

    ' Select the data from Sheet1 of the workbook.
    cmd = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Bhinder$]", cn)
    cn.Open()
    cmd.Fill(DataSet1)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = DataSet1.Tables(0)
    cn.Close()
End Sub
```

This error i am getting

[image]

thanks

**More info:** VB application which i am working is not on SharePoint server, its on my computer and i have permission to read write update SharePoint excel file contents.

Comment: Why don't you download the file first into temp directory, then read it?

Comment: @T.S. Thanks for reply. In my project i need to read contents and edit them and save them back. and i do not have upload permission. I can directly open xlsx file from server in EXCEL, edit contents and directly save back to server. The xlsx file i provided in this question is just for testing purpose.

Comment: You mentioned web. I don't know how you planning to open a file via web. As far as I understand, if the file is on the remote server and served to you via Web Server, all you can do is download the file, change it and upload. If the file is on the server, which is visible from your machine, you can work with that file using `\\server\folder\file.xlsx`. In your example you going through `http` protocol and I don't believe it will work.

Comment: Hello T.S, sorry for late reply. In live environment this excel file is located in Sharepoint. I can directly open it, edit it and save it back to server from Microsoft excel, but dnt have permission to upload any file to sharepoint. and in my example i uploaded a test excel file on my regular hosting server to do test.

Comment: Sharepoint is a web server. So, this means that Excel has some built-in integration with sharepoint. When you work with sharepoint via excel, it most likely, downloads the file into internet sandbox and opens it from there, then uploads it back. You didn't mention sharepoint. Otherwise your question is already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496608/read-excel-file-stored-in-sharepoint-document-library

Comment: Hello T.S, the link you provided it gave me more broad idea, but i am still not able to resolve the issue. in link person talked about OpenXML, which is Microsoft SDK. I downloaded and installed it and try to run that test code, but **SPFile** not available in my VStudio. I imports documentFormat.OpenXML in my page but no solution with **SPFile**. any idea?

Comment: @T.S, I found Microsoft.sharepoint.dll  NuGet from this [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint.Client) but still **SPFile** not available in my windows form.

Comment: I said, all I wanted, specifically related to your question. 1 - you can't connect to web server and open a file, edit and save. Because you need to download file, edit, save, and upload when you work with web server. 2 - You are looking for wrong answer by asking wrong question. Your question should be "how to programmatically modify excel document hosted on sharepoint", or similar. Check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57803/how-to-modify-an-office-word-excel-file-in-sharepoint-programmatically

Comment: and this http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC0QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsharepoint.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F82436%2Fcreate-excel-document-programmatically-in-sharepoint-2010&ei=4MaEU6v7KZPNsQSTvYHYCg&usg=AFQjCNGuATLB4pfBVCDq1Hdw1WGjCSODcg&bvm=bv.67720277,d.cWc&cad=rja

Comment: and all links you provided me thanks for it. and as per my small knowledge i found/understand that **SPfile** is only available in Sharepoint server, we cant get that function to run outside of the server machine. so there is no solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a virtual drive (eg. using Dokan Library). This way your application sees the file as it was local (using the new drive letter).